# Get the value of corresponding check box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html code where I would like to get the value of the `checkbox` which is been checked. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    Checkbox:
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue1" onclick="myFunction()"> Checkbox:
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue2" onclick="myFunction()"> Checkbox:
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue3" onclick="myFunction()">

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementsByName("myCheck")[0].checked.value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pass `this` to the event handler function. And access value from it. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7oaw2ehf/). Use `addEventListener` rather than inline Check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7oaw2ehf/1/)

Comment: You must be looking for `radio` buttons. Or you are expecting multiple values in `innerHTML`

Comment: Simply just pass this object with myFunction(this) and set value as document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  obj.value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**

```html
Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue1" onclick="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue2" onclick="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue3" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelector('[name="myCheck"]:checked').value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE :** Above method only selects first checked element, to get all use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

```html
Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue1" onclick="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue2" onclick="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue3" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name="myCheck"]:checked'), function(v) {
      return v.value
    }).join(' ');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>
```

---

**NOTE :** If you want only select one element at a time then you need to go with `radio` instead of `checkbox`

```html
Checkbox:
<input type="radio" name="myCheck" value="myvalue1" onclick="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="radio" name="myCheck" value="myvalue2" onclick="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="radio" name="myCheck" value="myvalue3" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelector('[name="myCheck"]:checked').value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @jasna : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` (this is the current element) to function `myFunction` like this

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  var value = element.checked ? element.value : '';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue1"  onclick="myFunction(this)">
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue2" onclick="myFunction(this)">
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue3" onclick="myFunction(this)">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

or if you want to get all values

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="myCheck"]:checked'),
      values = [],
      len = checkboxes.length, i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    values.push(checkboxes[i].value);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = values.join(',');
}
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue1"  onclick="myFunction()">
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue2" onclick="myFunction()">
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue3" onclick="myFunction()">

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll('[name=\'myCheck\']:checked');
  var str = '';
  [].forEach.call(checked, function(item) {
    str += item.value + '<br>';
  });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue1" onchange="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue2" onchange="myFunction()">Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="myvalue3" onchange="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>
```